# How to List value are possible String combination in java?

Tags: java, string, arraylist, combinations

i have one arrayList

```
List value = new ArrayList();
```

this arraylist are value is = {a,b,c,d}

i have required combination to string using this arraylist

Required Output: abcd,bcd,acd,abd,abc,cd,bd,bc,ad,ac,ab,a,b,c,d,null

If it's possible? then please send me code....

It's my code but not perfectly work

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
public class PossibleCombination {

public static void main(String[] args) {




    List segList = new ArrayList();
    for(int i=65;i<70;i++){
        segList.add((char)i);

    }
    int segSize = segList.size();
    int[][] a = new int[segSize][2];
    int i;

    for(i=0; i<= segSize-1; i++)
    {

        a[i][0] = 0;
        a[i][1] = 1;

    }

    boolean b1 = true;
        int t =0;
    while(b1)
    {
        StringBuffer stb = new StringBuffer();
        for(i=0;i<segSize; i++)
        {
            if(a[i][0]==0)
            stb.append(segList.get(i));
        }

        System.out.println(stb);

        if(t>=a.length){
            t=0;
        }
        int Pos=t;
        while(a[Pos][0]>=a[Pos][1])
        {
            if(Pos<segSize-1)
                Pos++;
            else
                break;
        }
        a[Pos][0]++;
        Pos--;
        while(Pos>=0)
        {
            if(a[Pos][0]>0)
            {
                a[Pos][0]--;
                break;
            }
            Pos--;
        }
        t++;

        if(a[segSize-1][0]> a[segSize-1][1]){
            b1 = false;
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Yes! It certainly is! Now, so we can help you, what have you tried ?

Comment: Please share code you've tried so far

Comment: Please think about how to do this yourself, write some code, and if you can't solve it, show us your code and ask a question. People are not going to do you homework for you - that way, you wouldn't learn anything.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, It is definitely possible. However, it will of course require exponential time.

I will leave the actual implementation to you, but here are some hints.

The easiest way to do this is recursively, but that will take a lot of stack space very quickly.

Another way to do this is via some kind of breath-first expanding of the resulting list. This can be done iteratively with a FIFO queue.

Comment: thanks Syd Kerckhove..but i have required a simple and eassy code

Answer (score 0):

```
List<String[]> value = new ArrayList<String[]>();
String[] item = {"a","b","c"};
value.add(item);
```